# How can I rewrite this nginx "if" statement?

Tags: nginx

For example, I want to do this:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 6.0" || $http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 7.0" (etc, etc)) {
    rewrite ^ ${ROOT_ROOT}ancient/ last;
   break;
}
```

instead of this:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 6.0") {
    rewrite ^ ${ROOT_ROOT}ancient/ last;
   break;
}
if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 7.0") {
    rewrite ^ ${ROOT_ROOT}ancient/ last;
   break;
}
```

Nginx rejects this syntax (minus the (etc, etc)), and I don't see anything in the docs about this.

Also, we opted not to use $ancient_browser directive, so that's not an option.

Comment: In this case it's as simple as `if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE [67]\.")`. You forgot that it's regexp.

Comment: @AlexeyTen you should write an answer with that -- IMO it's preferable to the other solution offered.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Edit:**

As Alexey Ten didn't add a new answer, I'll edit mine to give his better answer in this case.

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE [67]\.")
```

**Original answer:**

Nginx doesn't allow multiple or nested if statements however you can do this :

```
set $test 0;
if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 6\.0") {
  set $test 1;
}
if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 7\.0") {
  set $test 1;
}
if ($test = 1) {
  rewrite ^ ${ROOT_ROOT}ancient/ last;
}
```

It is not shorter but it allows you to do the check and put the rewrite rule only once.

**Alternative answer:**

In some cases, you can also use | (pipe)

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ "(MSIE 6\.0)|(MSIE 7\.0)") {
  rewrite ^ ${ROOT_ROOT}ancient/ last;
}
```

Comment: You can also use | (pipe) as an alternative like: if ($http_user_agent ~ "(MSIE 6.0)|(MSIE 7.0)")

Comment: Note: as ~ does a regexp match, the '.' should be escaped as '\.' in all cases

Comment: You can also use the map with two variables, for example:
https://serverfault.com/questions/760380/how-to-specify-several-variables-in-the-map-directive-of-nginx