# Remove part of URL using Nginx with Proxy Pass

Tags: nginx

I'm running a web application through nginx and I need to remove part of the URL (?debug), whenever it may come up, for example:

From
https://example.com/web?debug#menu=accounts

https://example.com/web?debug#menu=orders

To
https://example.com/web#menu=accounts

https://example.com/web#menu=orders

My nginx configuration file had the following location block:

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://example.com;
    }
```

I've looked online on ways to accomplish this, but nothing works.  I've tried the following, but the url is passed as is, no changes:

```
    location ^~ \?debug# {
           if ($request_uri ~* "\?debug#(.*)") {
                    rewrite ^\?debug(.*)$ $1 break;
                    proxy_pass  http://example.com/$1;
           }
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://example.com;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `?debug` is the query string. It is not part of the normalised URI used to match `location` and `rewrite` commands. Do you want to remove the query string, or only query strings that contains the word `debug`?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I want to remove any query string that has the word debug only. i.e. https://example.com/web?debug#menu=orders must be changed to https://example.com/web#menu=orders but https://example.com/web?debug=files#menu=orders can be allowed to go through as is.  I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: You could try: `if ($args = "debug") { rewrite ^(.*)$ $1? last; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Tried it, it's still going through with no change.  Based on your previous answer re "?debug" being a query string, I did some more digging and found this code 'if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)debug([^&]*)&?(.*)") { set $args $2$4; rewrite "^" $scheme://$host$uri permanent; }' but that removes all instances of ?debug it finds. I want something that only removes ?debug if there are no values being passed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.  Here's the code.

```
    location / {

            set $test 0;

            if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)debug([^&]*)&?(.*)") {
                    set $test 1;
            }

            if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)debug=files([^&]*)&?(.*)") {
                    set $test 0;
            }

            if ($test = 1) {
                    set $args $2$4;
                    rewrite "^" $scheme://$host$uri;
            }

            proxy_pass      http://example.com;
    }
```

Further help from the answers at these links:

[Nginx Redirect - Remove a specific query parameter from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384776/nginx-redirect-remove-a-specific-query-parameter-from-url)

[How can I use an "or" operator in an nginx "if" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756330/how-can-i-use-an-or-operator-in-an-nginx-if-statement)